# My terminal doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Tags: command-line

When I open terminal, the start text like:

```
maryam@laptop: $
```

doesn't appear in the first line of terminal. Also any command like `cd` or `ls` doesn't work. I can't do anything in my terminal.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your shell type may be incorrect. See if your /etc/passwd file lists any console like /bin/bash next to your user, like so:

> root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash